Azure function triggers before file is finished uploading
I have two azure environments (dev/staging) and they are behaving differently.
Each have a blog storage, files are stored as block.
Each have a function with a blob trigger.
Each had the same file uploaded via SFTP.
In one environment, things work as expected. The file is uploaded, then the function is called and the file is processed.
In the other environment, the function is called prematurely and only part of the file is processed.
I'm trying to figure out what the difference is that's causing this change in behavior. What should I look into?

Personally I am not a friend of the blob trigger, I suggest using EventGrid as it allows more control. Or your uploading part sends a queue/service bus message.

This is not something I have encountered but there are some possible causes that come to mind:

Polling trigger is used. This can be inconsistent, check Event based implementation.

Chosen plan. Consumption plan can have up-to 10 minutes delay. So if you have your development environment or both environments using consumption plan  results can be inconsistent.

Using Always On for App Service. If there are differences between environments, this can cause issues (mostly slowness, perhaps missed events)

And also I would check that the environments are actually separate and that there are no hidden dependencies (using same App Service, etc.)


This part also says that

